# Flutter animated sliver header

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to create a profile header sliver that can animate.

[image]

If you consider above image, `Section 1` is what we see in the fully expanded sliver, and `Section 2` is what we want to see in pinned mode.

Now I would like transition to move the image - purple circle - to the side, shrink it slightly, and also move the name and the links.

I can achieve all of that but one thing: How to center them in the expanded view.

As I have to use transform to move widgets around, I cannot simply use a centring widget like column or center. And I didn't find a way to calculate the exact position to center the widget, as it needs the size of the widget, that I don't have.

Comment: SliverPersistanceHeader will help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I am using `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` and it provides `shrinkOffset` that will be used on linear interpolation(lerp method).

Then `CompositedTransformTarget` widget to follow the center widget.

On this example play with `targetAnchor` and `followerAnchor` and use `t`/`shrinkOffset` to maintain other animation.

```dart
class SFeb223 extends StatelessWidget {
  const SFeb223({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: MySliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(),
            pinned: true,
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 1333,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySliverPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final LayerLink layerLink = LayerLink();
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    double t = shrinkOffset / maxExtent;

    return Material(
      color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.2),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment:
                Alignment.lerp(Alignment.center, Alignment.centerLeft, t)!,
            child: CompositedTransformTarget(
              link: layerLink,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: lerpDouble(100, kToolbarHeight - 10, t),
                  width: lerpDouble(100, kToolbarHeight - 10, t),
                  decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: layerLink,
            targetAnchor: Alignment.lerp(
                Alignment.bottomCenter, Alignment.centerRight, t)!,
            followerAnchor:
                Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topCenter, Alignment.centerLeft, t)!,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [Text("Sheikh")],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => kToolbarHeight * 6;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      false;
}
```